# How to use $push update modifier in MongoDB and C#, when updating an array in a document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've run the following code in mongo shell:

```
db.unicorns.insert({name:  'Dunx',  loves:  ['grape',  'watermelon']});
```

and now I've something like this in my MongoDB collection:

```
{name: 'Dunx', loves: ['grape', 'watermelon']}
```

As you can see `loves` is an array.

**Question**

How can I write C# code, with the official C# driver, that does the following:

```
db.unicorns.update({name: 'Aurora'}, {$push: {loves: 'sugar'}})
```

The above code runs just fine in mongo shell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it should be something like this:

```
unicorns.Update(Query.EQ("name", "Aurora"), Update.Push("loves", "sugar"));
```

Comment: How to do this thing currently using C# driver 2.0.0 of mongodb?

Comment: @Faraz Ahmad see answer below

Answer (score 12):

I would like to also illustrate how to do it using a different syntax

```
var filter = Builders<Unicorn>
             .Filter.Eq(e => e.Name, "Aurora");

var update = Builders<Unicorn>.Update
        .Push<String>(e => e.Likes, like);

await fantasyContext.Unicorns.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: Is there a way that this can be done with `Builder<BsonDocument>`? If not, what do you need to specify when you define the object (`Unicorn` in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with the updated syntax and regular `BsonDocument`s instead of defined objects, use the following:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name": "Aurora");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push("loves", "sugar"):

// you can also use the async update method from Alex's answer here
var result = fantasyContext.Unicorns.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```